# Layer animation removed from UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, core-animation, calayer

I am adding an infinitely repeating CALayer animation to the cells in a UICollectionView.  For some reason, whenever I return to the app after sending it to the background, or return to the view controller after pushing another one on top of it, the animations are removed from the cells.  Please let me know if you have any idea why this might be.

Answer (score 0):

When switch app or ViewController, the system will let animations on layer stop(complete), so you can set `removedOnCompletion` to `NO`(default is `YES`), it will work.